# Can't get setNeedsDisplay not working with my custom view to show changes

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to create a CGRect inside of a custom view (rectView) that will move up and down as you move a slider.

My slider's IBAction calls the following method: (which get's called fine)

```
- (void)moveRectUpOrDown:(int)y
{
    self.verticalPositionOfRect += y;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

My drawRect method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGFloat size = 100;
    self.rect = CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width / 2) - (size / 2), 
                                 self.verticalPositionOfRect - (size / 2), 
                                 size, 
                                 size);
    CGContextAddRect(context, self.rect);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

My custom view's initWithFrame calls the drawRect method using setNeedsDisplay, but for some reason the moveRectUpOrDown won't call drawRect.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

For clarity the entire implementation is below:

```
//ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "rectView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet rectView *rectView;
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender;
@end

//ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize rectView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.rectView = [[rectView alloc] initWithFrame:self.rectView.frame];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender 
{
    UISlider *slider = sender;
    CGFloat sliderValue = slider.value;
    [self.rectView moveRectUpOrDown:sliderValue];
}
@end

//rectView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface rectView : UIView
- (void)moveRectUpOrDown:(int)y;
@end

//rectView.m
#import "rectView.h"

@interface rectView ()
@property CGRect rect;
@property int verticalPositionOfRect;
@end

@implementation rectView
@synthesize rect, verticalPositionOfRect;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.verticalPositionOfRect = (self.bounds.size.height / 2);
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)moveRectUpOrDown:(int)y
{
    self.verticalPositionOfRect += y;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGFloat size = 100.0;
    self.rect = CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width / 2) - (size / 2), 
                                 self.verticalPositionOfRect - (size / 2), 
                                 size, 
                                 size);
    CGContextAddRect(context, self.rect);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}

@end
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I would imagine it would be a lot more efficient to just add a `CALayer` and animate it up and down as opposed to redrawing all the time

Comment: Haven't even looked into that yet, but I'll look into it now. I'm basically doing this as an exercise to get my head around the basics of Quartz

Comment: So you've verified that `-drawRect:` is not being called? Or is it called but not drawing?

Comment: It's not being called at all, I put an NSLog in there to test. The drawRect is only being called once in the views initWithFrame, but it's not getting called when the slider's value is changed (setNeedsDisplay *is* being called from slider's IBAction) but it's then not calling drawRect?

Comment: Is `self` the actual view? or the parent. Maybe try `[self.myView setNeedsDisplay]`

Comment: `self` is an instance of my custom view, which is a subclass of UIView. That means self is a view right?

Comment: This is a head scratcher.  A UIView subclass calls setNeedsDisplay in one method that we know is getting called, but the drawRect method is not.  When might that happen?  view is hidden? alpha==0??  +1 on all these good questions.   @Jarrod, can you post the whole implementation?

Comment: Yeah I've been scratching my head all morning haha, I'll post the whole implementation in the question, give me a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so the answer is the view is never actually added to the `viewController`'s view..

You have an `IBOutlet` to your `rectView` - so I assume you dragged a `UIView` component onto the `view` in Interface Builder and then changed it's class to `rectView`, which is all fine **BUT** in `viewDidLoad` you wipe over this object with a new one

```
self.rectView = [[rectView alloc] initWithFrame:self.rectView.frame];
```

So this is now no longer the object that was loaded from the xib.

Subsequently this view is never actually added to the view hierarchy so it's never going to draw itself as it does not make sense.

So the solution is to remove the line I highlighted above.

---

#### Notes

I would probably still go with my other answer for such an implementation but it's helpful to get tripped up and learn new things.

`rectView` does not follow naming conventions. Ideally you should start your class name with a 2-3 letter prefix (possibly your initial's or company name) followed by a camel cased named.

Comment: Also I think I agree your other idea is a better implementation :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you initialize CGFloat size.  Can you put a value in there and see how it works?  The rest of the code looks okay to me.

Comment: That, and you probably want to set a fill color.  As an aside, using UIBezierPath for simple drawing is invariably easier than using the full power of Core Graphics.

Comment: Apologies, that was just a typo that wasn't actually in my code, I fixed it now. Problem still remains though.

Answer (score 1):

An easier thing would be to just add a `UIView` and animate this around.

Add an ivar for this `UIView`

```
// .h
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *animatedView;

// .m
@synthesize animatedView = _animatedView;
```

then just replace your logic with this

```
- (void)moveRectUpOrDown:(int)y;
{
    CGRect frame = self.animatedView.frame;
    frame.origin.y += y;

    // If you want the change to animate uncomment this
    // [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
    //                  animations:^{
    //                      self.animatedView.frame = frame;
    //                  }];

    // If you don't want the change to animate uncomment this
    // self.animatedView.frame = frame;
}
```